# Applying ob_get_clean() to multiple classes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update multiple divs but can`t get it working.

This works as expected.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'update_basket' );
function update_basket( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="bas" style=""><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span> 
    <?php 
    $fragments['.bas'] = ob_get_clean(); 
    return $fragments;
}
```

When I add the second div class, the output doesn`t get updated at all.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'update_basket' );
function update_basket( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="bas" style=""><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></span> 
    <?php $fragments['.bas'] = ob_get_clean(); ?>
    <?php ob_start();  ?>
    <div class="search-form"> Your Basket:<br/> 
        <a style="" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"> <?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?> - <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    $fragments['.search-form'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```

Comment: At first I thought you might have had a scope problem but I tested it and you don't.

Have you tried a var_dump($fragments) to see what's being passed back?

Comment: I am not sure why but the same code worked on my local machine but not on the server. I created 2 different function to solve the problem just now.

Comment: Do you have the same PHP version on both?